# How to verify that some nodes exists in a path using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to get all paths between two nodes so that at least one node from a list of nodes exists in those paths.

how can I do this using cypher ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have provided your list of nodes as a cypher collection, would this do the job?

```
MATCH path=(start)-[r:*1..100]-(end)
WHERE ANY(node_on_path in NODES(path) 
  WHERE node_on_path IN node_collection)
```

You may also try using a list of values against which the nodes on the path are checked, something like

```
MATCH path=(start)-[r:1..100]-(end)
WHERE ANY(node_on_path in NODES(path)
  WHERE node_on_path.some_property IN list_of_acceptable_values)
```

Comment: You don't need to specify max hops. In this case, you can just have `[r:*1..]`.

Comment: That's right, not necessary. But you probably don't want to recommend infinite path patterns without knowing the OPs data.

Comment: Totally agree. Just that someone new to Cypher may not realize you can omit min and/or max.

Comment: what should I do if I want to check only middle nodes and exclude the first and last node ? and how can I get a collection of nodes ?

Comment: You can exclude first and last node by slicing the collection produced by `NODES(path)`, try something like `NODES(path)[1..LENGTH(path)-1]`. There are many ways to get collections of nodes, e.g. `COLLECT()`. Can you be more precise? Also, take a look at [aggregation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-aggregation.html) and [collection functions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-functions-collection.html)